# How to align an iframe to text baseline?

Tags: html, css

I would like to find a way to align the bottom of an iFrame to the baseline of text the iFrame is inline to, in this case, the text inside the list item (HTML is below). I would prefer a solution that doesn't modify the iFrame style (which is code generated) but instead works with the surrounding HTML.

```
    <ul class="itemList">
        <li class="item">
            first item
            <div style="display: inline-block; margin-left: 20px;">
                <iframe scrolling="no" style="border: 0; width: 80px; height: 16px;">
                    <!-- iframe content here -->
                </iframe>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: doesn't modify the iframe style?  What text are you wanting to vertical-align is to? Can we get a full example so we have something to work with?

Comment: Seems like what your doing with an iFrame should probably done with AJAX and you wouldn't have this problem?

Comment: @Senica, I want to vertically align the bottom of the iFrame to the text baseline in the li tag, which in this case is "first item".

Comment: @Jleagle, our system requires an iframe for namespace isolation purposes. The iframe is, in fact, populated via AJAX.

Comment: How can you change the iframe's vertical-align without editing its styles? Also, isn't `vertical-align:bottom` the default styling? Do you have a live example we could look at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give you DIV wrapper around the iframe a class or an id.  I'm going to call is wrapper `<div class="wrapper">`

You could do something like this:

```
<style>
li.item{ position:relative; }
.wrapper{ position:absolute; bottom:0px; right:0px; }
</style>
```

If you know your line-height (let's say it's 16px), you could do `position:relative; top:-16px;` on the wrapper.

As noted above, you can also use `vertical-align:bottom`, but I'm not sure this will work for what you are wanting.